# Dropdown menu hover bad?

Tags: jquery, menu

please I have problem with dropdown menu. When I´m over item in menu, which has subitems, they show me but when I move mouse over them, the background of item disapper and I don´t know, how to solve it.
Here is website: http://www.poridsiweb.cz/vojta/

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$("ul#nav").children('li').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('a:first').stop(true,true).animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 -5px)"}, 200);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('a:first').animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 -150px)"}, 200);
});
```

Note that this code was not tested.

Comment: I've changed it a little bit to work for all your links in the menu. You welcomed!